# Common root of homogenous polynomials

Tags: field-theory

I've been thinking about this problem for a while, and could use a hint!

> Let $f_1, \dots, f_m$ be positive degree homogeneous polynomials in
>   $k[x_1, \dots, x_n]$. Prove that if $n > m$, then $f_i$ share a non-trivial common root in the algebraic closure: there is a point $c := (c_1, \dots, c_n) \in \overline{k}^{\oplus n}$ such that $f_i(c) = 0$ for each $i$.

Comment: How much commutative algebra/algebraic geometry are you willing to use?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I know a decent amount of commutative algebra, I also just learned the Nullstellensatz. (as in IX in Lang)

Comment: For instance, this will follow quite easily from Krull's generalised principal ideal theorem.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Unfortunately, I do not know this theorem.